# Can I seek to a position inside a Memory-mapped file?

Tags: java, io, nio

I would live to have a memory-mapped file in Java NIO so that I can randomly move anywhere in the file to read any portion of it, pretty much like a seek method. Is that possible to do with a memory-mapped file, the same way you do with a RandomAccessFile.

NOTE: The file will be in READ/WRITE mode.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried position(int)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is small enough to fit into one ByteBuffer, you can use `position(int)`. Another option is to randomly access the buffer with `Xxx value = getXxx(offset)` or `putXxx(offset, value)`

If you have more than 2 GB you will need an array or list of ByteBuffers to map the entire memory (assuming you have a 64-bit JVM)